Issue while converting string to date datatype of a column in Spark SQL
I am trying to convert the datatype of a column from string to date. I'm getting error like this

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Using below SQL
Case when TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy')=last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) then date_format(last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')),'MM/dd/yyyyy') else 
Case when (DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')),1)) in ('6')) then date_format(last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')),'MM/dd/yyyyy') 
else 
Case when (DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')),2)) in ('6')) then date_format(last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')),'MM/dd/yyyyy') 
else 
Case when TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy') <> last_day(date_format(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) and (DAYOFWEEK(TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy')) in ('6')) then DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1),'MM/dd/yyyy') else 
TO_DATE('06/11/2024','MM/dd/yyyy') end end end end as AsOfDate

My expected result is  at the end i need resulted column as 06/11/2024 for above example as date datatype
Is anything wrong? Do i need to change anything in the sql?

Start by removing code, and when it works, then you know where the issue was. And then figure out what is causing the issue.
